# How to overwrite a table in RDS Postgres?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When I write a Glue Dynamic frame using below

```
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = dyf, catalog_connection = catalog_connection_name, connection_options = {"dbtable": "table_name", "database": "db_name"}, transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
```

it appends the data to the existing table. I rather want to overwrite it. How can this be done ?

Comment: I even used  "preactions":"drop table if exists table_name;" like below
`datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = dyf, catalog_connection = catalog_connection_name, connection_options = {"preactions":"drop table if exists table_name;" "dbtable": "table_name", "database": "db_name"}, transformation_ctx = "datasink4")`
but it still appended data

Comment: Did you try mode as SaveMode.Overwrite

Comment: can you share the syntax @BaluVyamajala

Comment: I don't know the syntax in Python or with Glue, but with spark-scala `.write.format("jdbc").option("driver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("url", "jdbc:url...").option("batchsize","1000").option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false").option("user", "username").option("password", "password").option("dbtable", destTableName).save();`